# leading term of the hilbert polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi!
I'm trying to solve a exercise from Harris & Morrison "Moduli of Curves":

Exercise 1.13: Use Riemann-Roch to show that, if $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^r$ has degree $d$ and dimension $s$, then the leading term of the Hilbertpolynomial $P_X(m)$ is $ \left( \frac{d}{s!} \right) m^s$.

But I can't see how to use Riemann-Roch here.

Thanks in advance for your tips

Thorbjørn

Answer (score 2):

Hints, not answers:

Do you understand how this works when $s=1$? What is the relationship between RR for a projective curve and the Hilbert polynomial of that curve?

I suspect that H+M are using Riemann-Roch to refer not just to the result for curves, but to [Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch%E2%80%93Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem), which allows you to compute the Euler characeristic of any vector bundle on any projective variety. The Wikipedia article I linked shows how to use this to deduce RR for curves. Concatenating that with your answer to the question in my first paragraph will give you a Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch computation of the Hilbert polynomial for $s=1$. Then generalize to arbitrary $s$.